# How to speed up code comparing file sizes/names?

Tags: ruby, file

I've got two main file servers and a big backup server, but someone has misorganized the backup server over some time now, and I need to check to make sure there are no files on the backup server that *aren't* on the main servers.

So I thought I'd write some quick code in Ruby to do so, which just uses a list of all files on each drive (found using File.glob) and checks for the existence of files on the main drives with File.size and File.basename.

Problem is it takes a while!! Each file between the main drives compared to the backup drive takes ~0.8s each, and given a drive with hundreds of thousands of files, this isn't going to work.

Any suggestions? I'm assuming my way is very inefficient.

Comment: Hundreds of seconds does not sound like it won't work. Just be patient! How many hundreds do you have? Why can't you just dump out the directory structure as well-formatted data (e.g. JSON, CSV, YAML) and compare at the data level?

Answer (score 2):

Forget ruby, just read manual for `rsync` command. You can use `dry-run` or other mix of options to just compare both main directories without copying files. It will be much faster, in terms of execution and time spent on making this work.

Comment: To clarify - the issue is that the directory structure is unorganized on the backup system. Files aren't going to be in the same folders as they are in the main servers. So I need to check on a filename/size basis, and not use directories..

Comment: Can you paste some code? It will be easier to tell how you can improve it when you can actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir.glob` returns an `Array`, so you'll end up needing to scan the full list of files for each file you're searching for. If you've got 100,000 files, that means you'll be doing 100,000^2 operations. You might speed things up quite a bit by instead incorporating a `Set`, which has constant time access, reducing the workload to 100,000 operations. You can try something like this:

```
require 'set'
files_to_search = Set.new(Dir.glob('/that/path/**/*'))
files_to_search.include?('foo')
```

You might also be running into other constraints, however, such as memory, or the fact that Ruby isn't comparatively all that fast, so if `Set` doesn't do the trick, you might want to try something using a shell tool. Michał Młoźniak's `rsync` solution might do the trick, or you could probably come up with a handful of other ways to patch together shell commands and get the information you're looking for. You could check out `diff` for example, perhaps paired with `find`.